# What inspired the idea of Dragons who grow to maturity very quickly, but then live extremely long lives?

Tags: magical-creatures, temeraire

In Naomi Novik's Temeraire series Dragons are seen to mature very quickly and then live a very long time. From the information in the books Dragons seem to reach adult size in around a year, sexual maturity in at most 2 years, but can then live for up to two centuries.

In real life, as a general rule, lifespan is correlated with the time to reach maturity. What inspired Novik to break this convention and create her dragons with this specific life cycle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Temeraire Comes Out Talking, Thinking for Himself**

Not conclusive but author Naomi Novik suggested once in an NPR interview a possible motive for her design choice:

> “ Temeraire comes out talking, thinking for himself," Novik says, "and immediately starts overturning all of Laurence's
> assumptions because he doesn't take things for granted.”

https://www.npr.org/2016/02/27/467810806/a-writer-engineers-historical-fiction-hack-add-dragons

That is, a possibility may be that Novik’s motive is to have a fully-matured dragon for narrative purposes, and her dragon’s fictional biology flowed from that choice.